# Javascript Using a for loop to get the last chars of id`

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
[id^='signaturePad-']
```

I want do a `for-loop` to find every div with the above, and use end of that div to replace "id" in the code bellow

```
 [id].map(function () {
   SignaturePad["SignaturePad" + id] = new SignaturePad
     (document.getElementById('signaturePad-'+targets))
   });
```

Comment: _"use end of that div"_ ? What ?

Comment: `$("[id^='signaturePad-']").each(function(){ var id = this.id.split("-")[1]; });` - and then use the `id` variable for whatever the heck it is you're trying to do with `SignaturePad`...

Comment: Replace with what? There are several problems with that example code.

Comment: Do you mean the text value of `id` following `-` character?

Comment: @testndtv Are there more than one `-` characters in `id`?

Comment: @guest271314 - If it were my code and I knew there'd be more than one hyphen I'd use a regex match to get exactly the parts I needed, but that's out of scope for a question this unclear...

Answer (score 2):

You could include a `data-*` attribute to elements instead of performing separate processes on `id` of `element

html

```
<div id="signaturePad-0" data-id="0"></div>
<div id="signaturePad-1" data-id="1"></div>
<div id="signaturePad-2" data-id="2"></div>
<div id="signaturePad-3" data-id="3"></div>
<div id="signaturePad-abc" data-id="123"></div>
```

javascript

```
$("[id^=signaturePad]").each(function() {
   SignaturePad[
     "SignaturePad" + this.dataset.id || $(this).data().id
   ] = new SignaturePad
     (document.getElementById("signaturePad-" + targets))
   });
})
```